Group Structures of a Group Extension
Let $A,G$ be groups with $A$ abelian, and $0 \to A \xrightarrow i E \xrightarrow \pi G \to 0$  a group extension. We denote the induced action of $G$ on $A$ as $g \cdot a$. A paper that I am reading claims that for a set-theoretical section $s: G\to E$ of $\pi$, every element of $E$ can be written in the form $i(a)s(g)$ for some $a\in A, g\in G$ and that there is a 2-cocycle such that: $$s(g_1)i(a_1)s(g_2)i(a_2)=s(g_1g_2)i(g_2\cdot a_1+ a_2+\sigma(g_1,g_2))$$ where $s:G\to E$ is a set-theoretical section of $\pi$. I would like to find a proof of this.
I first looked in "An Introduction to Homological Algebra" by Charles A. Weibel and noticed two things. Firstly, the cocycle relations given in the paper and Weibel are not the same. In particular, for $f,g,h\in G$, Weibel gives it (on page 180) as $$f \cdot \psi(g,h) - \psi(fg,h)+\psi(f,gh)-\psi(f,g)=0$$
while the paper gives it as $$ f \cdot \sigma(g,h) + \sigma(fg,h)-\sigma(f,gh)-\sigma(f,g)=0$$
I notice that one can obtain one of these realtions from the other by simply letting $\psi(g,h)=\sigma(h,g)$. However, I am not sure how one is meant to define group cohomology to obtain the relation in the paper.
Secondly, the proof of Theorem 6.6.7 in Weibel suggests that the group law of $E$ should be $$s(g_1)i(a_1)s(g_2)i(a_2)=s(g_1g_2)i(a_1+ g_1 \cdot a_2+\psi(g_1,g_2))$$ where $\psi$ is the factor set determined by $E$ and $s$. In particular, a proof of a result in the paper relies on $a_2$ not being acted on and the proof breaks down with this group law. Unfortunately, the paper in question does not cite any sources for its version of group cohomology, and after looking for a while, I have only found Weibel's version.

It seems that this is just a matter of writing elements as $s(g)i(a)$ rather than $i(a)s(g)$?

Rotman has a proof in Chapter 7 of his Introduction to the Theory of Groups, 4th Edition. The difference between the paper and Weibel are likely a matter of convention on the side of the action and how to express elements of $G$.

Thank you, I will have a look.

Basically, the divergence in the formulas just comes down to the choice of writing elements in $E$ as $s(g)i(a)$ (in the article you are reading) or as $i(a)s(g)$ (in Weibel's book). Of course both are perfectly reasonable, but Weibel's is more common.
Note that the second formula you quote from Weibel is a misinterpretation on your part, in the formula the elements of $A$ are on the left and those of $G$ on the right, so the formula is actually
$$ i(a_1)s(g_1)i(a_2)s(g_2) = i(a_1+g_1\cdot a_2+\psi(g_1,g_2))s(g_1g_2).$$
It would certainly not have made any sense to have $g_1$ act on $a_2$ as in the formula you gave.
In the notation of your article (at least according to what you wrote, you might have made a mistake), the action of $G$ on $A$, and the $2$-cocyle $\sigma$, are defined by
$$\begin{align}
i(a)s(g) &= s(g)i(g\cdot a) \\
s(g)s(h) &= s(gh)i(\sigma(g,h)).
\end{align}$$
In Weibel's convention, you get
$$\begin{align}
s(g)i(a) &= i(g\cdot a)s(g) \\
s(g)s(h) &= i(\psi(g,h))s(gh).
\end{align}$$
Note that in the first case this defines a $G$-action on $A$ on the right, and in the second case this is an action on the left (much more common). Those two actions are related to each other by making $g^{-1}$ act instead of $g$.
You get the cocycle relations by computing $s(f)s(g)s(h)$ in two ways by using associativity, and you can convert between $\sigma$ and $\psi$ by
$$\psi(g,h) = (gh)\cdot \sigma(g,h)$$
using the left action of $G$ on $A$.

But if you were using a $G$-action on the right, then you would write $a \cdot g$ rather than $g \cdot a$.

I agree, but this is the notation in the question, and possibly in the article. It might be a mistake on the OP's part, I don't know.

Ah, that clarifies things a lot. Thank you very much!
